# convert boost::multiprecision integer to builtin float type (double)

Tags: boost, arbitrary-precision

I need to convert from `boost::multiprecision::int128_t` to `double`.

For smaller ints, I use:

```
template<typename flt_t>
  flt_t as_flt() const { return std::ldexp (static_cast<flt_t>(val), -frac_bits); }
```

with `val=int128_t, flt_t = double`

But `static_cast<double>(int128_t)`

seems to fail

error: invalid static_cast from type ....

Answer (score 2):

Try the convert_to method.

```
boost::multiprecision::int128_t some128Int = 141324;
double someDoubleNumber = some128Int.convert_to<double>();
```

Answer (score 1):

According to John Maddock (answered on boost users list)

The C++03 way is:

```
cpp_int i = 1;
i <<= 128;
double d = i.convert_to<double>();
```

In C++11 you can just use a static_cast (explicit convertion operator).

Comment: How to do rounding on converted value ?